# Where exactly to use this code in httpd.conf?

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I have a list which I saved from a previous install which I have marked as 'stop automated tools' which looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept} ^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} ^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(POST)
RewriteRule .* - [R=400]
</IfModule>
```

Can somebody refresh my memory as to where I should be using this file and also, if possible, what the rules do?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a [mod_rewrite declaration](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) and it goes either in a directory directive in the httpd.conf configuration file or you can put it in a `.htaccess` file at the website itself if you want to change it without using SSH to get into the box.

```
<Directory /website/root>

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept} ^$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} ^$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(POST)
    RewriteRule .* - [R=400]
    </IfModule> 

</Directory>
```

**Update**
Per your question about what the rules do, you're looking for empty (eg ^$) [HTTP headers and connection requests](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond). If any of the variables you're checking are empty then the system fails the request with an error code [400 (Bad Request)](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html).

The code would go into the [directory directives](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directory) for the various websites where applicable in your configuration file, whether it be a `vhost` include or the regular `httpd.conf` file.

Comment: Thank you.  When I used this previously I'm fairly sure that wherever I used it applied server-wide as opposed to on a site to site basis (.htacess).  For this to work servver-wide, where exactly should I be adding it?  Also, can you refresh my memory as to what it actually does?  Thanks.

Comment: @user1061571 there should be a `<Directory />` on the `httpd.conf` or related config files if you place it inside of it, will affect all domains within that server.

Comment: Thank you @Prix, I'll have a look through.